# Should the existence of a closed-form solution inform the choice of robust regression method?

Tags: regression, least-squares, robust

Suppose one has a linear least squares problem of the form \begin{align} \xi^* = \textrm{arg min} \ \sum_{i = 0}^n \left \lvert  \ {\bf v}^T({\bf x}_i) \ \xi - c({\bf x}_i)  \ \right \rvert^{\ 2}  \in \mathbb{R}^m, \ 6 \leq m \leq 12  \end{align} 
where ${\bf x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$, ${\bf v}({\bf x}_i) \in \mathbb{R}^m$,   and $c({\bf x}_i) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Under the $\ell^2$ norm as written, the problem has a closed form solution given by $$ \xi^* = {\cal M}^{-1} {\boldsymbol{ \cal b}}, $$ where \begin{gather*} {\cal M} = \sum_{i}^n {\bf v} {\bf v}^T ({\bf x}_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m} \\
\boldsymbol{\cal{b}} = \sum_{i=0}^n c({\bf x}_i) \ {\bf v}({\bf x}_i) \in \mathbb{R}^m.
\end{gather*}

Furthermore, suppose that the number of points, $n$, is such that $$ 2^{15} \leq n$$ and that the data is generally noisy, to the degree you would expect a 3D point cloud corresponding to the projection of a depth map from a stereo camera to be.

This number of outliers are significant enough to the point where the linear least squares problem does a relatively poor job of recovering $\xi^*$ and a robust regression method is required for an accurate solution.

**My question boils down to this:**

Are some robust regression methods particularly well-suited for problems that when initially formulated under the $\ell^2$ norm, have closed form solutions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "omit" in your last paragraph, or what your sample size has to do with anything.  The number of data points doesn't prevent a closed-form solution to the least-squares problem from being used computationally, as all the relevant matrices can be constructed one observation at a time.

Comment: 1) I only see an l2 norm in the expressions. Where is the l1 norm? 2) What do you mean by"least squares problem under the l1 norm"? If you use l1 loss it's no longer least squares. Or did you mean something else? 3) What are $v$ and $c$? 4) Omit=admit? 5) Why is a closed-form solution needed? This requirement would rule out many robust regression methods

Comment: @jbowman Please excuse me! Instead of "omit" I meant to write "admit". I included the sample size as I thought erring on the side of too much information would be better than giving too little.

Comment: @user20160 Yes, you are correct. I misspoke when referring to the $\ell^1$ norm. It should be the $\ell^2$ norm. I've updated the question accordingly.  Here ${\bf v}$ and $c$ are vector and scalar functions of the points ${\bf x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$ respectively.  It isn't necessary for the robust regression method to have a closed form solution, however my question is whether or not some robust regression methods are particularly well-suited for linear least squares problems that have closed form solutions as opposed to non-linear least squares problems that don't have closed form solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the 'original' least squares problem has a closed form solution, I'm not aware of a reason why this would affect the *quality* of any robust regression methods relative to others. However, it would reduce the *computational cost* of robust methods that involve repeatedly solving least squares problems at each step. For example, this would be true for [M-estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) (using the [iteratively reweighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) algorithm) and [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).

In any case, you have a standard linear regression problem, which is the most commonly investigated setting for robust regression. So, many robust methods are available to choose from. Keep in mind that robust regression problems themselves typically don't have closed form solutions, even for linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to minimize absolute error instead of squared error, I take it. I don't think you're going to find something with an analytical solution, but [Support Vector Regression](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf) does what you want, I think, i.e. outliers do not exert "undue" influence on the slope of the regression line.